# Странный тоннель в Altel Neo

Tags: terminal

После автоматического обновления прошивки, в конфигурационном файле Altel  появился тоннель на сторонний ip 188.225.38.126, с чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1):

У нас в организации была схожая ситуация. Недавно обновилась прошивка межсетевика, появились новые записи отличные от предыдущих конфигов.
При этом сбилось время в самом Altell, на 8+ часов
Мы решили проблему загрузкой старого конфига алтель, либо можно решить удалением записи с этим туннелем.
Время поправили через set date 2016.06.25-17:19 в режиме настройки.
Сужба поддержки сначало было брыкалась, но потом признала что это их косяк с обновлением.
А вообще пользуйтесь нормальным экраном и будет вам счастье.